How to train a Siamese Network with triplet loss using tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss?
I intend to train a siamese neural network with triplet loss using semi-hard triplet mining technique.
However, I am pretty confused of how tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() do the tricks.
I've already tried 3 following ways, but I am not sure which is the right way for my case.
1. Train a basic cnn model with tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()
According to its official document and tutorial, I assume tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() forms the triplet itself during loss calculation, so should I just feed one image with its label when I fit the model?
If this is the case, then Ill have a simple pretrained resnet model trained with the tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss, does that mean that I am training the model as a siamese model?
It seems like the post and the answer in post imply that a resnet model trained with tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() is essentially a siamese model.
Train a simple resnet model with tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss:
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import ResNet50V2
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

# Generate dummy data
num_samples = 64
train_images = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
# Dummy labels for the anchors
labels = np.random.randint(0, 10, num_samples)
# build the model
resnetmodel = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3))
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnetmodel.output)
model = Model(resnetmodel.input, x, name = 'Embedding')
model.compile(loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(margin=1.0), optimizer = optimizers.Adam(0.0001))
model.fit(train_images, labels, batch_size = 8, epochs = 10)

2. Another way is a more common way to build the siamese neural network with triplet loss.
You repeat the base embedding model three times as anchor, positive and negative stream, and feed triple(3 images) and one label into the model during training, and then compiled the model with tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() to employee the online semi-hard triplet mining.
Here is how I construct siamese model:
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import ResNet50V2
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from keras import Input
from keras.layers import *
# Generate dummy data
num_samples = 64
anchors = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
positives = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
negatives = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
# Dummy labels for the anchors
labels = np.random.randint(0, 10, num_samples)
base_cnn_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3))
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_cnn_model.output)
convnet = Model(base_cnn_model.input, x, name = 'Embedding')
input_anchor = Input(name = 'anchor', shape = (256,256,3)) 
input_pos = Input(name = 'positive', shape = (256,256,3))
input_neg = Input(name = 'negative', shape = (256,256,3))
feat_vecs_anchor = convnet(input_anchor)
feat_vecs_pos = convnet(input_pos)
feat_vecs_neg = convnet(input_neg)
# concatenated layer 
output_concatenate_layer = concatenate([feat_vecs_anchor, feat_vecs_pos, feat_vecs_neg], axis = 1, name = 'concat')
opt = optimizers.Adam(0.0001)
#compile model
siamese_network = Model(inputs = [input_anchor, input_pos, input_neg], outputs = output_concatenate_layer)
siamese_network.compile(loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(margin=1.0), optimizer = opt, metrics = []) 
siamese_network.fit([anchors, positives, negatives], labels, epochs=10, batch_size=8)

However, I am confused about the label because, from my understanding, the semi-hard triplet mining requires the label for each image to find the minimum negative distance among the data of different labels.
It doesn't make sense to provide only one label for an image triple.
3. Build a siamese neural network with triplet loss feeding three labels for each image in image triple.
I saw this in another post.
I've tried to feed 3 images and 3 labels of anchor, positive and negative into the model as follow.
# Generate dummy data
num_samples = 64
anchors = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
positives = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
negatives = np.random.random((num_samples, 256, 256, 3))
# Dummy labels for the anchor, positives and negative
dummy_labels = np.random.randint(0, 10, num_samples*3)
labels = np.reshape(dummy_labels, (num_samples, 3))
bbase_cnn_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3))
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_cnn_model.output)
convnet = Model(base_cnn_model.input, x, name = 'Embedding')
input_anchor = Input(name = 'anchor', shape = (256,256,3)) 
input_pos = Input(name = 'positive', shape = (256,256,3))
input_neg = Input(name = 'negative', shape = (256,256,3))
feat_vecs_anchor = convnet(input_anchor)
feat_vecs_pos = convnet(input_pos)
feat_vecs_neg = convnet(input_neg)
#compile model
siamese_network = Model(inputs = [input_anchor, input_pos, input_neg], outputs = [feat_vecs_anchor, feat_vecs_pos, feat_vecs_neg])
siamese_network.compile(loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(margin=1.0), optimizer = optimizers.Adam(0.0001)) 
siamese_network.fit([anchors, positives, negatives], labels, epochs=10, batch_size=8)

Then, I encountered an error below highly likely coming from the tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() expect labels y_true to be provided as 1-D integer Tensor with shape [batch_size] of multi-class integer labels.
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/utils/keras_utils.py", line 61, in call  *
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/losses/triplet.py", line 120, in triplet_semihard_loss  *
        labels = tf.reshape(labels, [lshape[0], 1])

    ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 24 elements to shape [8,1] (8 elements) for '{{node Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_INT64, Tshape=DT_INT32](y_true, Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [8,3], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [8,1].

I also came across a helpful post explaining the semi-hard triplet loss, while they didn't go into details about how to build the siamese model.
I don't know which way to go if I want to train the siamese neural network with triplet loss using the online semi-hard triplet mining.
Does anyone has any idea? Thank you!
Please feel free to ask for further details.
